# Pre-load image in inactive UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that holds several tabs of which one tab (third Tab, inactive at startup) contains a very large image.

Since I want to allow quick reaction time once the app is running, I want to load the image during App startup.

How can I "pre-load" this third tab when the app is started without displaying it?

I thought of switching to the tab and back programmatically, but that is a bit odd. I'd like to do the load whilst the application startup screen is still showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call .view on the UIViewController that is holding the tab, it will force it to load.